# Command Handler not responding for EditorSelectionDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i am building my custom Editor. But when i right click on my desired file and try to open it with custom  editor via "Open With" option, my command handler does not work. Do i have to use **locationURI** under **menuContribution** tag with **commandId** in **plugin.xml** for this? If it is then how? Please have a look at my current plugin.xml for better understanding.

**Plugin.xml**

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        class="launcher.ChartEditor"
        default="false"
        id="launcher.ChartEditor"
        name="ChartEditor">
  </editor>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        id="launcher.openChartEditor"
        name="OpenChartEditor">
  </command>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="launcher.ChartEditorHandler"
        commandId="launcher.openChartEditor"> 
  </handler>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Open With...' menu just opens the editor directly. It does not use any command or handler. There is no other way to contribute to the 'Open With' menu. The `EditorSelectionDialog` is the same.

To use your command and handler you do need to using a menuContribution (or a tool bar contribution) but this will have to somewhere other than Open With.

The standard 'Open With' action opens the selected editor passing it the `IEditorInput` for the current selection. This will usually be an `IFileEditorInput` from which you can get the file.

Comment: Ok. But how can i then open a editor based on selected file. My editor shows a chart based on the selected file contents. That's why i used command handler

Comment: Well Open With opens the selected editor on the current selection. Why doesn't that work? Added some info on that to the answer.

Comment: your updated answer has a valid point. But in my EditorPart class's init method when i use "IFileEditorInput tui = (IFileEditorInput) input"  i get NoClassDefFoundError exception. What is wrong here?

Comment: Probably you haven't added a dependency in your MANIFEST.MF on the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin which contains `IFileEditorInput` but it is hard to say with no information.

Comment: I have found that when i check with "if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput)" then if code block does not execute but if i use toString method on input outside of if block then it prints "org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput(-----). What is wrong here?

Comment: No idea, that should work. You are putting the plugin dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF? Putting them just in the Java Build Path or including jars in the plugin won't work.

Comment: Everything worked perfectly. The problem was IEditorInput input was of IPathEditorInput type not the IFileEditorInput type

Comment: `FileEditorInput` implements `IFileEditorInput` and `IPathEditorInput` so either should work.

Comment: You need to have declared the plug-in that contains it as a dependency in your plug-in manifest. Did you? And you can use `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE#.openEditor()` to open an editor on a specific file programmatically.